# Download a fix number of directories from ftp server

Tags: shell, download, ftp

I have an FTP server with thousands of directories. What I want to do is to download a specific number of them (for example, 500 directories) using a shell script. How can I do that? I tried wget with -Q command. For example, "wget -Q25MB", which gives me 25MB of data. The problem is that each folder has a different size. Therefore, using this command will stop the download in the middle of getting a specific folder.

Comment: We need more information on the directory structure inside your FTP. Also, please provide clear examples of what you tried for us to be able to fix your eventual mistakes.

Comment: I have several hundreds of directories in my ftp server. Each directory has a number of image files. What I want to do is to retrieve a specified number of them, say 500 out of 1,000,000 every night. To make it clear, here is the pattern of the folders I currently have : 
610186098  02/23/2016  12:47:00 AM
610187047  05/24/2016  07:57:00 PM
610187071  01/20/2016  04:02:00 AM
610188005  02/23/2016  12:47:00 AM
610188075  04/29/2016  09:33:00 PM
610188078  05/24/2016  07:57:00 PM
...

Comment: P.S. Folder names are the identification number of students and their contents include the scanned copy of their educational documents. Also, every night new folders will be added to the list of folders in ftp server, so there's a varied number of folders in the server each day.

Comment: P.S. I want to download 500 directories and their contains at 10 pm and delete the successfully transferred directories from ftp server. 
stopping download in the middle of a directory is not acceptable.

Comment: This may be a naive approach, but I would do it like this: 1) download the list of folders in the ftp (or at least the beginning of the list), then 2) for each listed folder, download it and then delete it. When reaching 500 deletions, exit. Don't forget to check if the download of each folder is complete before deleting something...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. how can I download the list of folders in the ftp using shell script?
I can get the list from the ftp using ftp>  ls . filelist.txt 
BUT I do not know ho to get the list from local host

Comment: It depends on how you connect to the FTP. I don't even know your platform (windows? linux?), nor do I know how you specify the password to connect...

Comment: I use fedora and I want to write a shell script to do that. the script runs automatically every night and copy 500 directory. my current script download the whole ftp and I want to change that.

Comment: I have a username and pass and use it like ftp://username:pass@my_ftp_address

Answer (score 1):

Assuming wget returns an error when the download get interrupted:

```
#!/bin/bash
to_del= # empty to_del in case you want to copy-paste this to a terminal instead of using a file
username=blablabla
password=blablabla
server=blablabla
printf -v today '%(%Y_%m_%d)T'
# Get the 500 first directory names to download
ftp -n "$server" << EOF | grep -v '^\.\.\?$' | head -n 502 > "to_download_$today.txt"
  user $username $password
  ls
  bye
EOF
# Then, you can download each folder one by one:
while read -r dir; do
  if [[ -e $dir ]]; then
    echo >&2 "WARNING: '$dir' already exists!"
    continue # We don't download or remove it. Manual action needed
  fi
  if wget "$username:$password@$server/$dir"; then
    to_del+=("$dir")
  else
    # A directory was not successfully downloaded, we delete the temporary files
    echo >&2 "WARNING: '$dir' download failed, skipping..."
    rm -rf "$dir"
  fi
done < "to_download_$today.txt"
# Now, delete the successfully downloaded folders using a single FTP connection
{
   printf 'user %s %s\n' "$username" "$password"
   for dir in "${to_del[@]}"; do
     printf 'del %s\n' "$dir"
   done
   printf 'bye\n'
} | ftp -i -n "$server"
```